# A quickie for the cryptic crossword enthusiasts: Here is the clue. / Cut cut! / What crazy, bloodthirsty creature remains? (5 letters)

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, cryptic-clues, letters

> Here is the clue.
>
> Cut cut!
>
> What crazy, bloodthirsty creature remains? (5 letters)

EDIT I added the word 'crazy'. Apologies that I missed this out before.

Please use typical cryptic crossword strategies to solve this but some lateral thinking may be required.

In the unlikely event that there are multiple valid answers then the one that gets the most up-votes in the next couple of days will be accepted.

If you are not sure that your answer is correct, then it isn't! If you get the intended solution then you will be 100% certain of the reason.

The answer is a single word. Please give the word and explain the cryptic techniques you used. I used two very straightforward ones.

Hints

1. > Don't ignore the *lateral thinking* tag.
2. > Make sure you use all the information provided.
3. > No technical knowledge is needed (apart from a familiarity with cryptic crosswords) and this is a word that I'm sure everyone will know.

Comment: I hope the answer doesn't involve inserting an extra letter into "cut" to get something where blood is sometimes involved...

Comment: @randal'thor Awww, you take the fun out of everything...

Comment: @randal'thor - If that is your answer, submit it and see if you win! It doesn't really fulfil the conditions if I have understood you correctly.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Nah, I'd probably get flagged as offensive (maybe rightly so). No number in brackets at the end to tell us how long the clue is? :-(

Comment: Okay, I'll add the number.

Comment: if it weren't for the one word requirement, my guess would've been "the IS" (Islamic State) , you can get  there by removing two ("Cut cut!" ) of the words in the first sentence ("Here is the clue."). They're crazy and bloodthirsty, but I don't know about creature, ;)

Comment: Are you saying the remaining creature's name is 5 letters or the original word?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the answer:

> If you cut the head from the word 'cut' (leaving 'ut') then cut these two letters from 'the clue', you are left with 'hecle'. The word 'crazy' implies an anagram, so rearranging these letters gives 'leech' which is a five-letter bloodsucking creature.

Comment: That was my answer. As promised I'll wait for a while to see what other answers there may be and accept whatever gets the most votes.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - But shouldn't the clue be "Cut cut cut!"? Since you "cut cut" to get "ut", and then "cut ut" to get "he cle"?

Comment: @Alconja - You are of course right. I only realised that that would be better after I had already posted the puzzle and people had started answering. In future I shall have to wait 24 hours before setting a puzzle. It's so easy to miss something if you do it in a rush.

Comment: Or if you want to make it obvious- `cut(cut(cut),....)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> SLICE

Cut cut!
What bloodthirsty creature remains?

> When you slice something, you are cutting into it. Also, once you chop off the first letter of SLICE, you are left with LICE, bloodsucking insects.

And of course it is 5 letters long.

Comment: If this is the answer, I don't like the question: it sounded as though the *answer* was meant to be a bloodthirsty creature. It is clever though.

Comment: Except that 'lice' is plural (of louse). I specified 'creature' which is singular. Also 'slice' is not a creature. 'louse' has five letters but it is far too distant from the clue to be valid (IMO)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> TROLL.

Explanation:

> the "cut" command on a computer is implemented by Control+X. In cryptic-crossword lingo, "cut" can suggest either an abbreviation or a shortening of a word by removing some letters. "Cut"="Control+X" can be thought of as an abbreviation, and we can remove some letters from "Control+X" to get *trol*. Since we want a 5-letter creature, the answer looks like TROLL - we all know those can be [bloodthirsty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10470/5373)!

Wow ... have I managed to answer a cryptic-crossword question before Bailey M? :-D

Comment: @chaslyfromUK [In light of the response to rand al'thor... this is nothing but a troll question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/the-traveler-and-the-blood-thirsty-troll#comment31506_10466) ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Not to mention that the larger part of the [internet trolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll) just "Control+X" once and "Control+V" a million times the same thing.

Comment: As per the conditions, I'm not entitled to exclude this answer. As a hint to others, here is the main problem with this answer  as I see it.  In cryptic-crossword terms, to get from 'trol' to 'troll', would need a clue that used the phrase 'looks like' or 'sounds like' or that in some way specified adding a letter was needed. My question has none of those.

Comment: Another troll question!